# JAVA-How to set a character to a specific position in a word in a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a method to set a character to a specific position in a word in a string. The method looks like "setChar(l, w, c, d)", and I want it to cause the c-th character in the w-th word of the l-th line to be "d". For example, lets say I have a string "I am a student", after setChar(1, 2, 2, "X"), the sentence becomes "I aX a student".

Still have no clue how to do this, so please help me, better with specific code, thank you guys very much!!!!

Comment: So...you want us to do it for you? Do you know that a `String` is immutable?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, for now I just know I should create a StringBuilder object for the string I have, really have no idea what to do next....

Comment: @nhgrif For now I just know I should create a StringBuilder object for the string I have, really have no idea what to do next....

Comment: Could you make your post a bit more clear please?

Comment: You should give it a bit more effort, honestly.  You've done basically nothing.  Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to concatenate.

```
    int indx = 5;
    char c = 'U';
    String s = "Hello World";
    s = s.substring(0,indx)+c+s.substring(indx+1,s.length());
    System.out.println(s);
```

Out `HellUWorld`

A bit cleaner, replacing the character in the backing char array and creating a new string.

```
    char[] c = "Hello World".toCharArray();
    c[5] = 'U';
    String s = new String(c);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `String` is immutable, you can't change the content of any given `String` object.  Secondly, all arrays in Java are 0 based, this is important for the example...

Basically, you need to use `StringBuilder`, which uses an internal `char` array to store the individual characters.  It provides the means to add, remove and change the content of the `char` array via it's method operations.

Once you have the `String` wrapped in a `StringBuilder`, it's a simple process to use `setCharAt` to modify and individual character.

Once you made your modifications, you need to assign the contents of the `StringBuilder` back to the `String`

For example...

```
String text = "I am a student";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
sb.setCharAt(3, 'X');
text = sb.toString();
System.out.println(text);
```

Now, remember, like much of the Java API, `StringBuilder` is `0` based, this means that the first character of the `StringBuilder` is at index `0`, not `1`

Take a closer look at the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) API for more details

Comment: Thanks, ur answer is helpful too:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string is a multi-line string (i.e. it has line breaks in it), you could split the string on the line breaks:

```
String[] lines = string.split("\n");
```

then split the string on the whitespace:

```
String[] words = lines[l].split(" ");
```

then reassemble it with a StringBuilder while changing that character in words[w][c].

Something like that.  It would probably be more efficient to do it in an old fashion C-like manner.

Comment: Thanks, ur answer is helpful too:)